# Обработка ошибок в Go

Tags: golang

При обработке ошибок в коде очень часто повторяется один и тот же шаблон кода

```
result, error := execute()
if error != nil {
   return nil, error
}
```

Как избежать подобных повторов?

Comment: Это вольный перевод темы с английской версии SO?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16963298/golang-error-handling-techniques?rq=1 ?

Answer (score 1):

Прочитать статью Роба Пайка ["Ошибки как значения"](http://4gophers.com/article/oshibki-eto-znacheniya#.VSLaCVmT43w):

> "Программы пишутся на основе значений, и зная, что ошибки тоже
>   значения, их можно использовать в своем коде для реализации некоторой
>   логики.
>
> Конечно, общий принцип для обработки любого значения ошибки, это
>   проверка на nil, но есть множество других вариантов работы с
>   значениями ошибки. И использование этих вариантов помогут сделать вашу
>   программу лучше, избавят ее от повторяющегося шаблонного кода, который
>   появляется при использовании стандартных проверок.
>
> Используйте язык для упрощения обработки ошибок.
>
> Но помните: что бы вы не делали, ошибки нужно обязательно проверять!"

То-есть подобных проверок не избежать - единственно можно их прятать внутри функций-оберток или-же сокращать их количество, меняя логику приложения.

Comment: Ссылка хорошая, но стоит пару абзацев в ответ добавить, чтобы стало ясно как это относится к вопросу *"Как избежать подобных повторов?"*

Answer (score 0):

Более компактная запись

```
if result, error := execute(); error != nil {
   // Обработать ошибку
}
```

Можно дополнить отложенным вызовом defer

```
defer hadleError()

if result, error := execute(); error != nil {
   return nil, error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Подобных проверок никак не избежать. Программисты на языке Go должны страдать из-за отсутствия исключений.

Авторы Go пишут подобные проверки. Так что это можно считать общепринятым способом обработки ошибок.